# How to serve static files with mod_wsgi and Django?

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I would like to serve static `plist` files using `mod_wsgi`. In have configured `apache` as follows

```
Alias /site_media/ "/var/www/mysite/media/"
<Directory "/var/www/mysite/media">
Order allow,deny
Options Indexes
Allow from all
IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>
```

When I go to `http://localhost/mysite/site_media/mac_config.plist` I get the error

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost/mysite/site_media/mac_config.plist
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^config/
^admin/doc/
^admin/
The current URL, site_media/mac_config.plist, didn't match any of these.
```

This error is telling me that `Django` is intercepting the request. How is it possible to serve this static file without having to use python to read the file from disk and respond with an http request?

Comment: Try http://localhost/site_media/mac_config.plist

Comment: @sdolan that worked. If I were to put this on a production server, would the url be `www.example.com/site_media/mac_config.plist`?

Comment: Yup.  The alias defines where you access the folder relative to the root of the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as `@sdolan` suggested, doing `localhost/site_media/mac_config.plist` corrected the problem.